# Real-Time API is return null value

Tags: real-time, foursquare

I have set up the real-time api for User Push API in FourSquare. Even, I am getting response but all values are null. No values like 
{"id":null,"createdAt":null,"type":null,"timeZone":null,"user":null,"venue":null}. When i add anything in foursquare after it post the data to our link within a miniute, but null value.

I have added few checkins in foursquare but i got null values and format of the object is 
{"id":null,"createdAt":null,"type":null,"timeZone":null,"user":null,"venue":null}.

Am i doing anything wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the values passed in the request URL are null, or could there be some problem with your code to read from the JSON string? Can you post an anonymized snippet of the JSON that gets sent to you to be sure?

Comment: When i do any checkin's after that I am getting response data like this {"id":null,"createdAt":null,"type":null,"timeZone":null,"user":null,"venue":null}. This is the format setup in their document for real-time api.

Comment: Can you confirm that the "null" values are missing even before you parse the json object? What library are you using to receive the push messages?

Comment: parse json obj in this format {"id":"12","createdAt":131,"type":"checkin","timeZone":"New","user":{"id":"1","firstName": "Ji","lastName":"Ji","photo":"h","gender":"male","homeCity":"NY,NY","relationship":"self"},"venue":{"id": "1","name":"HQ","contact": {"twitter": "FS"},"location": {"address": "NY","lat": 40.3,"lng": 73.9,"city": "NY","state": "NY","postalCode": "1","country":"USA"},"categories":[{"id": "4","name":"T","pluralName": "Tech","shortName": "T","icon": "h","parents": ["Offices"],"primary": true}],"verified": true,"stats":{"checkinsCount":7,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":1},"url":"h"}}..

Comment: Parsing is done exactly the same as I need set for real-time API. but, still it gives an null value like {"id":null,"createdAt":null,"type":null,"timeZone":null,"user":null,"venue":null‌​}.

Comment: What library are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?